# Loading and Filtering Huge Amount of Data using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I am working on a project, and I am told that there could be a very large amount of data coming from each region. I am worry that the application may be slow once we go live. As a result, I asked the QA team to do a load testing. The manager said no because they don't have the tools and/or resources to do it. I'd like to get some feedback on anything that I can do to optimize the code.

I am thinking of moving the if statement into its own method, so it can be called from switch case passing the region. Then, in the if statement, I will do the LINQ to method syntax passing the expression(s). Instead of regionOrder.Where, it will be db.orders.where(passing the name,location, and date according to the search preference(s).

```
List<order> result = null;
List<order> regionOrder = null;

switch (region)
{
    case "NorthEast":
        regionOrder = db.orders.Where(x => x.Name == region).ToList();
        break;
    case "SouthEast":
        regionOrder = db.orders.Where(x => x.Name == region).ToList();
        break;
}

if (order.Name.IsNotNull() && order.Location.IsNotNull() && order.DateOrdered != null)
{
    result = regionorder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name && x.Location == order.Location && x.DateOrdered == order.DateOrdered);
}
else if (order.Name.IsNotNull() && order.Location.IsNotNull())
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name && x.Location == order.Location);
} else if (order.Name.IsNotNull() && order.DateOrdered != null)
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name && x.DateOrdered == order.DateOrdered);
} else if ( order.Location.IsNotNull() && order.DateOrdered != null)
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Location == order.Location && x.DateOrdered == order.DateOrdered);
} else if (order.Name.IsNotNull())
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name);
}
else if (order.Location.IsNotNull())
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Location == order.Location);
}
else if (order.DateOrdered != null)
{
    result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.DateOrdered == order.DateOrdered);
}
```

Comment: Remove `.ToList()` from your queries so that the data is not materialized to memory (but both `case:` statements are identical so not clear what your trying to do with that)

Comment: And all you need is 3 `if` statements - `if (order.Name.IsNotNull()) { result = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name); }; if (order.Location.IsNotNull()) { .... }; if (order.DateOrdered != null) { ... };` where `result` is `IEnumerable<order>`

Comment: Yes, I will change that. I had the regions hard coded; then, I added a parameter to select the region from a drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `.ToList()` means that its reading all records from the database in to an in-memory set. And there is no need for all those `if/else` blocks - all you need are 3 `if` statements and you code can simply be

```
IQueryable<order> regionOrder = db.orders.Where(x => x.Name == region)
if (order.Name.IsNotNull())
{
    regionOrder = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Name == order.Name);
}
if (order.Location.IsNotNull())
{
    regionOrder = regionOrder.Where(x => x.Location == order.Location);
}
if (order.DateOrdered != null)
{
    regionOrder = regionOrder.Where(x => x.DateOrdered == order.DateOrdered);
}
```

which will translate to the correct SQL query and return only the results you need. And then if you want to create an in-memory set that gets executed immediately

```
List<order> result = regionOrder.ToList();
```